# Providing ViewModels "without" Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

---

**Edit:** This question inspired me to create a [medium](https://medium.com/@guidelgado/viewmodel-from-dagger-to-hilt-223056dd9b?source=friends_link&sk=90ccb8a1074ced2600b9b9d6d0fa198e).

---

After reading this great [medium](https://proandroiddev.com/injecting-viewmodel-from-hard-to-easy-c06c0fe1c8e9) from [Elye](https://proandroiddev.com/@elye.project) I start thinking on how I was handling `ViewModels` (with or without a template). Normally I was going for the ***Dagger Android*** approach, the more verbose one with `Assisted Injected` `ViewModels` and generic factories, etc.

Luckily, the author show us (I'm only interested in `Dagger` solutions) that we can actually ditch all the factory logic and use a *"Simple Dagger Based Solution"*, where - simply put -, we move all constructor injected dependencies to field injection (yes they will be public, it gives me itches too, but it beats all the boilerplate and you can make them `protected`). `SavedStateHandle` remains in the constructor and `by viewModels()` comes to the rescue (in `Activity` or `Fragment`).

My **BaseActivity**:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VM : ViewModel, ...> : ... {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    protected val viewModel: VM by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(getViewModelClass()) }

    protected abstract fun getViewModelClass(): Class<VM>
    ...
}
```

I started by trying to change it into this:

```
protected val viewModel: VM by viewModels(getViewModelClass())
```

But it didn't work, so I copied the `viewModels()` and changed it to:

```
private fun viewModels(
    clazz: KClass<VM>,
    factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }
    return ViewModelLazy(clazz, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
}

protected val viewModel: VM by viewModels(getViewModelClass())
```

And it worked! But a warning was thrown...:

> Calling non-final function in constructor.

So I added this:

```
private fun initViewModel(): VM {
    val v: VM by viewModels(getViewModelClass())
    return v
}

protected val viewModel: VM by lazy { initViewModel() }
```

And finally the **BaseActivity** `ViewModel` logic became:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VM : ViewModel,...> : ... {

    private fun viewModels(
        clazz: KClass<VM>,
        factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
    ): Lazy<VM> {
        val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
            defaultViewModelProviderFactory
        }
        return ViewModelLazy(clazz, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
    }

    private fun initViewModel(): VM {
        val v: VM by viewModels(getViewModelClass(), getViewModelFactory())
        return v
    }

    protected val viewModel: VM by lazy { initViewModel() }


    protected fun getViewModelFactory(): (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
       ...
   }
```

No warnings, no compile-time errors, no run-time errors - it works!

Why can't my `Activities`/`Fragments` handle their `ViewModel`? They can, but:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VM : ViewModel, ViewBinding : ViewDataBinding> ... {
    ...
    protected val viewModel: VM by lazy { initViewModel() }
    protected val binding: ViewBinding by lazy { DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ViewBinding>(this, getLayoutResId()) }
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        ...
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.setVariable(getViewModelVariableId(), viewModel)
        ...
        initViews(binding, viewModel)
    }
}
```

I have this kind of setup logic and I don't want to repeat it.

So, what are your thoughts on this, useful or over engineering? Will I run into troubles?

Comment: I don't see how your new approach could ever get a `SavedStateHandle` if you intend to provide a custom factory. You can eliminate the `inheritance` if you want by relying on the Lifecycle API.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've added `factoryProducer` as a new parameter to `initViewModel`this way I made it possible or am I missing something?